# TikZ Make a graphical balance for equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-graphdrawing

I'd like to be able to draw a white `=` inside of the triangle, be able to rotate the balance and the equation and place the equations symmetrical yet not to close to the edge. It's quite hard for me.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
$2+2$ \hfill $4$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red!50!blue!70!white,ultra thick](-5.4,1) -- (5.4,1);
\fill[red!50!blue!70!white] (0,0.98) -- (-0.4,0) -- (0.4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the update with a `quick generating command` at the end of this post.

The center of a triangle could be easily obtained with the `barycentric` coordinate system provided by `TikZ`.

Define the three corner nodes of the triangle and say

```
\node[color=white]  at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {=};
```

in order to use weighted vertices (here all having the same weight, which corresponds to the true barycenter of the triangle then.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
$2+2$ \hfill $4$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0.98);
\coordinate (B) at (-0.4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0.4,0);
\draw[red!50!blue!70!white,ultra thick](-5.4,1) -- (5.4,1);
\fill[red!50!blue!70!white] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\node[color=white]  at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {=};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\winkel{20}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0.98);
\coordinate (B) at (-0.4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0.4,0);
\coordinate (rodleft) at (-5.4,1);
\coordinate (rodright) at (5.4,1);
\coordinate (balancetop) at (0,1);
\coordinate (rotatedleft) at ($(balancetop)-(\winkel:5)$);
\coordinate (rotatedright) at ($(balancetop)+(\winkel:5)$);
\draw[red!50!blue!70!white,ultra thick] (balancetop) -- (rotatedleft);
\draw[red!50!blue!70!white,ultra thick] (balancetop) -- (rotatedright);
\node[rotate=\winkel,above right] (LHS) at ($(rotatedleft) + (\winkel:1)$) {$2+2$};
\node[rotate=\winkel,above left] (RHS) at ($(rotatedright) - (\winkel:1)$) {$3$};
\fill[red!50!blue!70!white] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\node[font=\large,color=white]  at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {$\neq$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd update**

The macro `\equationbalance` checks the arguments `#3` and `#4` and prints either `=` or `\neq`, however, the angle must be specified still. I don't find it useful to calculate the angle from the values of `#3` or `#4` (from the Physics view: the angle would be not constant anyway, if there both sides of the scale hold unequal values)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% First opt arg: angle
% 2nd arg: inward shift of the labels 
% 3rd arg: left hand label
% 4th arg: right hand label
\newcommand{\equationbalance}[4][0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\winkel{#1}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0.98);
    \coordinate (B) at (-0.4,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0.4,0);
    \coordinate (rodleft) at (-5.4,1);
    \coordinate (rodright) at (5.4,1);
    \coordinate (balancetop) at (0,1);
    \coordinate (rotatedleft) at ($(balancetop)-(\winkel:5)$);
    \coordinate (rotatedright) at ($(balancetop)+(\winkel:5)$);
    \draw[red!50!blue!70!white,ultra thick] (balancetop) -- (rotatedleft);
    \draw[red!50!blue!70!white,ultra thick] (balancetop) -- (rotatedright);
    \node[rotate=\winkel,above right] (LHS) at ($(rotatedleft) + (\winkel:#2)$) {$#3$};
    \node[rotate=\winkel,above left] (RHS) at ($(rotatedright) - (\winkel:#2)$) {$#4$};
    \fill[red!50!blue!70!white] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
    % Works for simple integer expressions only
    \ifnum\numexpr#3=#4
    \node[font=\large,color=white]  at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {$=$};
    \else
    \node[font=\large,color=white]  at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {$\neq$};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\equationbalance[10]{1.5}{2+2}{3}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Could one move the text somehow a little bit inwards? It would be nice to get say three spots left and right where I can add x and y's. So they stay where they are.

Comment: @JoelDuscha: You mean 2+2 should go more to the left and 4 more the right?

Comment: the other way around, please

Comment: @JoelDuscha: Yes of course, I was confused

Comment: Always good to ask. I'm certainly more often confused and you already helped :D

Comment: @JoelDuscha: See the update, please

Answer (score 2):

With the new `TABcline` option to `tabstackengine` (`2018/03/05 (V2.10)`), this becomes a nice exercise.  The support macros `\balanceindent` and `\lever` control the indent of text from the ends of the lever and the lever to fulcrum distance, respectively.  The lever thickness is controlled by `\fboxrule` which is defined locally inside the main macro.  The main routine is

```
\balance[fulcrum inset]{left terms}{right terms}
```

The default fulcrum inset is `?`.  If it is set to `>` or `<`, the lever will be made to tilt in the appropriate direction.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\Leqtriangle[1][=]{%
  \stackengine{2pt}{\Ltriangle}{$\scriptstyle#1\mkern1mu$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\Ltriangle{\LARGE$\triangle$}
\newcommand\balanceindent{\kern10pt}
\newcommand\lever{\kern7em}
\newcommand\balance[3][?]{{%
  \TABbinary\TABstackMath\setstackgap{S}{0pt}\fboxrule=1pt\relax%
  \def\bangle{4}% TILT ANGLE
  \def\bsign{}%
  \ifx>#1\def\bsign{-}\else\ifx<#1\else\def\bangle{0}\fi\fi%
  \rotatebox[origin=b]{\bsign\numexpr-\bangle}{%
    \tabularShortstack{lcr}{\mathstrut\balanceindent#2 && #3\balanceindent\\%
    \TABcline{1-3}\lever &%
    \rotatebox[origin=t]{\bsign\numexpr\bangle}{\Leqtriangle[#1]} & \lever}}}}
\begin{document}
\balance[>]{2 + 2(4-3)}{6 - 6/2}

\balance[=]{2 + 2}{4}

\balance[<]{2 + 3}{7}

\balance{y}{42}
\end{document}
```

[image]